# Adding individual X and Y axis labels when using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-wrap

I am attempting to plot lots of graphs on the fly and I chanced upon the `facet_wrap` functionality. It produced the desired results until I realised that it was not assigning individual axes headings. There was just a single X and Y axis heading for a whole set of graphs. What I'm looking for is a way to assign individual axes headings for each graph.

Is this possible using the `facet_wrap` functionality at all?

Looking forward to any suggestions and advice.

Comment: Adding some example data, your current results and what you're expecting would be very helpful.

Comment: Take a look at `scales` argument for `facet_wrap`. Setting it to `free` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

(removed previous, incorrect, answer)

It is my understanding that if the axes of your plots are not the same (i.e. require different labels), the way to go would be with [multiple separate plots](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) (on the same page), and not with facet_wrap.

Comment: Hello, my query is to do with the 'labels' and not the scale as such. I have used scales="free" however I am wanting to plot separate x and y axis labels.